# How to get all rust items?

Tags: api, steam-web-api

I want to get all the rust items from the steam api with current steam price.
But it seems like that there is no such api endpoint for rust.

I can get the schema of all the csgo skins (without price):

https://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_730/GetSchema/v2/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

It seems like that IEconItems_APPID is only for some games (here csgo).

And if I can only get the schema of all rust skins do I need to send a request for every skin price?

Comment: The `rust` tag is for [the rust programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_\(programming_language\)), not [the Rust video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_\(video_game\)) which seems to be the subject of your inquiry. As such, I removed the tag.

Comment: ups my bad messed this up